# Caused by: java.io.IOException: No connection found to cluster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast, stress-testing

Hello working on microservices, when doing a stress test on start Hazelcast working fine but after some load **client is shutting down** exception came and **Caused by: java.io.IOException: No connection found to cluster** error occurred continuously. I am not able to solve this issue.

```
2022-04-04 17:34:29.926 ERROR 8 --- [o-8080-exec-172] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/offers_service] threw 
exception

com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientNotActiveException: Client is shutting down at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.notifyException(ClientInvocation.java:260) 
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.
invokeOnSelection(ClientInvocation.java:196) 
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.
invoke(ClientInvocation.java:143) at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:187) at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:182) at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.proxy.ClientMapProxy.getInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:251) at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:245) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal
(RequestContextFilter.java:100) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) 
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.
internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.
doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764) at 
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at 
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: java.io.IOException: No connection found to 
cluster.
at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.
checkInvocationAllowed(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:486)
at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocationServiceImpl.
checkInvocationAllowed(ClientInvocationServiceImpl.java:279)
at 
com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invokeOnSelection(ClientInvocation.java:
165)
... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you check heap usage on client, gc pauses etc? Are you able to reach servers from another client?

Answer (score -1):

Check for SSH connectivity between nodes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).